# Probability that population mean is within a range, given sample data

Tags: probability

I feel like I should have been able to find an answer to this and haven't, which leads me to believe I'm missing something obvious. Your insight is appreciated.

I have a set of sample data, n=73, with s=2.275 and mean of 1.821. Based on this sample, I need to calculate the probability that the *population* mean is in the range of +/- 1.289.

This is the reverse of the classic problem calculating the probability of a sample result from given population results, and all of the answers I've been able to find detail doing the calculation that way round.

Comment: You cannot do it that way round with classical frequentist statistics: the population mean is not a random variable.  See many previous questions here on [confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confidence-interval)

Comment: This seems related to Bayesian inference and not frequentist/classical inference as mentioned by @Henry

Comment: @RRMT Bayesian methods would need a joint prior for the mean and variance, preferably chosen before you see the data

Comment: @Henry yes. Agree